# Intermittent Blank video signal on live usb

Tags: boot

Just trying to get elementaryOS installed at all. Booted off a live usb. I see the screen that says "boot, edit config, command line", then it says something like "SGX disabled in bios", then a bunch of garbage looking data, and then the screen goes black.

Then my monitor turns off and says no signal, and every 5 seconds or so it'll turn back on, turn stay black, then turn off and say the same thing.
this is with a rtx 3060ti and a 10400. Im wondering if its an IGPU issue, but my IGPU is turned off in bios.

Comment: Does that "garbage looking data" include words that might be an error message? With regards to the SGX message, you can control this in your UEFI/BIOS by setting it to "Enabled". It would also be useful to ensure that "Secure Boot" is disabled.

Comment: All of this is already done. I couldnt tell you what the garbage data contains - its garbage data.
SGX can be enabled or disabled, eitherway i can get into elementary using nomodeset, but that obviously doesnt give me access to the full usage of my gpu, which is an issue.